# lnk2001 unresolved external symbol with public static variable

Tags: c++, templates, static

"file.h"

```
template <class ClassType>
class NewClass
    {
    protected:

    public:
        NewClass() {}
        ~NewClass() {}

        static long INITIAL_SIZE;
    };
```

"file.cpp"

```
template<class ClassType>
long NewClass<ClassType>::INITIAL_SIZE{ 50 };
```

"usage file"

in the main function

```
std::cout << NewClass<char>::INITIAL_SIZE << std::endl;
```

Can someone please tell me why this gives me a "lnk2001 unresolved external symbol" error?

So whenever I moved:

```
template<class ClassType>
long NewClass<ClassType>::INITIAL_SIZE{ 50 };
```

to the header file it would throw different error... but once I changed {50} to = 50:

```
template<class ClassType>
long NewClass<ClassType>::INITIAL_SIZE = 50;
```

it worked. I don't understand why, but the problem was the way I was setting the variable.

Comment: If the template class is located in lib (or dll), it should be used also in the dll with the `char`, otherwise the template class won't be compiled with the `char` argument.

Comment: And for the duplicate issue, you can't put the static declaration in the header file, so I can't see how it suppose to answer you're question.

Comment: @SHR _"you can't put the static declaration in the header file,"_ Wrong. You well can do so for templates. Also DLL is out of question, where did you get that from?

Comment: he got it from the fact that when I do declare it in the header file it throws an error saying static none const variables cant be initiated in header files.